# Click to close in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got a jQuery UI code with which I developed accordion which expands the div on click and doesn't contract the div on second click.

Code is hosted at https://ther8.com/signature/

Upon clicking Europe it pop down a div of content and how can I find & alter the code that's responsible to close the div upon clicking the Europe on the second time.

Thanks

Sample code (this code is different from code in the list mentioned)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            navigation: true
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="tit">Signature Collection</div>
            <div class="cap">BALI</div>
        </a>
    </h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            <img src="../../R8MASTERS/BALI_MASTER.jpg" width="100%" alt=""/>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post ur code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery-UI Accordion supports collapsing. http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-collapsible

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true, // Add this line and you're good to go
        navigation: true
    });
});
```